# How do I get the key of an item when doing a FOR loop through a dictionary or list in Python?

Tags: python

I am new to Python.

Say I have a list:

```
list = ['A','B','C','D']
```

The key for each item respectively here is 0,1,2,3 - right?

Now I am going to loop through it with a for loop...

```
for item in list:
    print item
```

That's great, I can print out my list.

How do I get the key here? For example being able to do:

```
print key
print item
```

on each loop?

If this isn't possible with a list, where keys are not declared myself, is it possible with a Dictionary?

Thanks

Comment: Don't use `list` as a variable name.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The answer is different for `list`s and `dict`s.

A `list` has no `key`. Each item will have an **index**. You can enumerate a list like this:

```
>>> l = ['A','B','C','D']
>>> for index, item in enumerate(l):
...     print index
...     print item
... 
0
A
1
B
2
C
3
D
```

I used your example here, but called the `list` '`l`', to avoid a clash with a reserved word.

If you iterate over a `dict`, you are handed the key:

```
>>> d = {0: 'apple', 1: 'banana', 2: 'cherry', 3: 'damson', }
>>> for k in d:
...     print k
...     print d[k]
... 
0
apple
1
banana
2
cherry
3
damson
```

Comment: Thanks, as yours was the first answer I will mark this as the accepted one.

Good point about the list variable name, it was just an example but good practise for me to remember that regardless.

Thanks to everybody else who submitted answers. I'm really finding it hard to get to grips with Python as I progress, coming from PHP.

Comment: also thanks for clarifying over the terms "key" and "index". PHP seems like to muddle these things all up into a big ball, or at least that's the way I learnt.

Answer (score 11):

You want the index, not the key. For this you can use [enumerate](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#enumerate):

```
for index, item in enumerate(l):
    print index
    print item
```

This is mentioned in the section [Looping Techniques](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#looping-techniques) in the Python tutorial which also covers looping over dictionaries while getting both the key and the value.

```
>>> knights = {'gallahad': 'the pure', 'robin': 'the brave'}
>>> for k, v in knights.iteritems():
...     print k, v
...
gallahad the pure
robin the brave
```

Answer (score 3):

You should use a dictionary, anyway you could do something like:

```
for index, item in enumerate(yourlist):
    print "index:%d item:%s" % (index, item)
```